# dbh->selectrow_array Unknown column <field> in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a fairly simple request as follows;

```
$self->{message_count} ||= $y->dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT count(*) FROM messages WHERE message_type 
                          IN ('user','system', 'notification') AND
                          gid = ? AND `read` = 0 AND mbox = ?", undef, $self->{ugroup} || 0, 1);
```

If I manually type this query into mysql, it returns the correct results.

When i run this query by browsing to the appropriate page on the website, I *sometimes* get the error

```
Unknown column user in 'where clause'
```

Refreshing the page clears the error.

'user' is simply a value that message_type may be set to - nothing special there.  I'm wondering what could possibly be causing this problem?

#### UPDATE

I tried releasing the code to our staging server and testing there.  I couldn't find a reason for this behaviour which just seems dodgy.  The code works fine on the staging server with no errors.  I tried the code on another dev server, no problems.  So, it appears it's something strange on my dev server.

Comment: `AND 'read' = 0` what that means?

Comment: read is just a column in the messages table. So the equivalent sql statement is SELECT count(*) FROM messages WHERE message_type IN ('user','system', 'notification') AND gid = 22 AND 'read' = 0 AND mbox = 1;  gid, read, mbox are column names.

Comment: why it's in quotes like string?

Comment: @mark, then 'read' must be without the quotes: `AND read = 0`. And you say you get the error sometimes.. in particular cases?

Comment: Read has to be quoted, I'd always assumed because it's a reserved word of some sort, but actually I don't know (I inherited the code).  If you try and execute the sql (directly or otherwise) without read in quotes mysql throws an exception.  However, I don't think it's relevant to the problem I'm having.

Comment: Yes indeed read is reserved and has to be quoted http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Are you sure that this is the exact query? The error would make sense if you were using backticks instead of single quotes.

Comment: You're correct it should be backticks - typo error on my part.  It is backticks in the code.  So, what do you think the problem is?  I can't work it out.

Comment: I think this may need some additional context. Are you sure this is the query that is having issues? What about the calling code? Is it a Catalyst/Dancer/Mojo app? Have you logged the queries before you call them with the bind params to see what they might look like? Why are you not using the return value? Are we looking at the exact code that is failing? Perhaps something is stripping '' around user? what is $y?

Comment: Yep I've logged the SQL that is being run, and it is exactly as I have have it above (and it works). I would be using the return value, except SQL is throwing an error at this point. Yes, this is the exact code that's failing. As I said, it's not even failing all the time, just sometimes.

Comment: What's the calling context? Do you assign `selectrow_array()` to a scalar, or an array? Perhaps `$y->dbh->{TraceLevel} = 15` may shed some light.

Comment: I've updated the code above to include the assignment. I'll try TraceLevel now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be restricted to my development server and I believe it's got upset.  I'm in the process of rebuilding it.